# Rails class method help - How to take the sum of the columns that is created today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to take the sum of the all the columns earn that have the date today. I am trying to make a class method.

How to take the sum of all the columns earn where the column dato have the date today and display it in view?

My controller:

```
class ReklamersController < ApplicationController
layout 'reklamer'
def index

@reklamers = Reklamer.find(:all)

end
end
```

My model:

```
  def self.total_on(date)
      where("dato(date) = ?", date).sum(:earn)
    end
```

My view:

```
<td><b><%= @reklamer.total_on(dato) %></b></td>

Index: Error: undefined local variable or method `dato'
```

Best regards,

A rails beginner

Comment: Can you state your problem in the form of a question?

Comment: Is it more clear now? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class method should be in your model, not in the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get a error in view that says: Error: undefined local variable or method `date'

Comment: There's probably something else in your view that references `date` because in the context of that method it should be defined.

Comment: Is there way to sum the columns in view?

Comment: Doing the summing in the view breaks the MVC pattern, its better to do it somewhere in the model as tadman had suggested. You can pass the date into the summing method, from the view or controller, so you don't have to do the summing in the view.